# Why can't the Java compiler find my Hilt class in launchFragmentInHiltContainer?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to implement the [custom `launchFragmentInHiltContainer()` method](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-hilt/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/HiltExt.kt#L38) in a Java project, and I've already gone through all the hoops of setting up kotlin and refactoring the reified parameters. However, when I try to compile the project, I am greeted by this puzzling error:

```
C:\Users\jedwa\AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\appname\MainActivityTest.java:55: error: cannot access Hilt_FragmentPersonalDetails
        HiltExtKt.launchFragmentInHiltContainer(FragmentPersonalDetails.class);
                 ^
  class file for com.example.appname.fragments.Hilt_FragmentPersonalDetails not found
```

`FragmentPersonalDetails` is a hilt-enabled fragment and works fine in production code. What is strange is that replacing FragmentPersonalDetails.class with a NonHiltFragment.class will allow the project to compile just fine.

What it will not do, however is stop a runtime error from occurring, which may be related. On replacing `FragmentPersonalDetails` with NonHiltFragment, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hilt test, MainActivityTest, is missing generated file: com.example.appname.MainActivityTest_TestComponentDataSupplier. Check that the test class is  annotated with @HiltAndroidTest and that the processor is running over your test.
```

which I have seen before, except this time I most definitely do have @HiltAndroidTest on my test class. I've finally hit the point where the error is internal enough that I have no idea how to go about fixing it, though it seems like a dependency error of some sort. Files provided below for reference.

The hilt-enabled FragmentPersonalDetails

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.atease.R;
import com.example.atease.databinding.FragmentPersonalDetailsBinding;
import com.example.atease.viewmodels.LoginViewModel;

import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint;

@AndroidEntryPoint
public class FragmentPersonalDetails extends Fragment {

    private FragmentPersonalDetailsBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentPersonalDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
        ViewModelStoreOwner store = navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.login_graph);
        binding.setViewModel(new ViewModelProvider(store).get(LoginViewModel.class));
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.nextButton.setOnClickListener(view1 ->
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FragmentPersonalDetails.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FragmentPersonalDetails_to_FragmentEmploymentDetails));
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

The test class that won't compile

```
import androidx.test.espresso.IdlingRegistry;
import androidx.test.espresso.accessibility.AccessibilityChecks;

import com.example.atease.fragments.SecondFragment;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidRule;
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidTest;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@HiltAndroidTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Inject DataBindingIdlingResource bindingIdlingResource;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void enableAccessibility() {
        AccessibilityChecks.enable().setRunChecksFromRootView(true);
    }

    @Before
    public void init() {
        hiltRule.inject();
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(bindingIdlingResource);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(bindingIdlingResource);
    }

    @Rule
    public HiltAndroidRule hiltRule = new HiltAndroidRule(this);

    //cycles through the nav-bar
    @Test
    public void testNavbar() {
        HiltExtKt.launchFragmentInHiltContainer(SecondFragment.class);
    }
}
```

My implementation of `launchFragmentinHiltContainer`. The only difference is that I took out the reified parameter types and added the extra class parameter, in order to be able to reference the methods from Java.

```
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.StyleRes
import androidx.core.util.Preconditions
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi

@JvmOverloads
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
inline fun <T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentType: Class<T>,
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    @StyleRes themeResId: Int = R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
    crossinline action: Fragment.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra("androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY",
        themeResId)

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(fragmentType.classLoader),
            fragmentType.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commitNow()

        fragment.action()
    }
}


@JvmOverloads
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
inline fun <T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentType: Class<T>,
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    @StyleRes themeResId: Int = R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
    factory: FragmentFactory,
    crossinline action: Fragment.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra("androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY",
        themeResId)

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = factory
        val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(fragmentType.classLoader),
            fragmentType.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs

        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commit()

        fragment.action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the function in Java. I changed the signature to match the original `FragmentScenario.launchInContainer`.

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.StyleRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;

import java.util.Objects;

public class HiltHelper {
    public static void launchFragmentInHiltContainer(Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass, Bundle fragmentArgs, @StyleRes int themeResId) {
        Intent intent = Intent.makeMainActivity(new ComponentName(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), HiltTestActivity.class))
                .putExtra("androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY", themeResId);

        ActivityScenario.launch(intent)
                .onActivity(activity -> {
                    Fragment fragment = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentFactory()
                            .instantiate(Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentClass.getClassLoader()), fragmentClass.getName());

                    fragment.setArguments(fragmentArgs);
                    ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
                            .commitNow();
                });
    }
}
```